# home energy consumption dataset

Tags: data-request, energy

I am a Ph.D. student of power system engineering. I'm studying about home/building energy management in my thesis, and I need the dataset of building appliance and equipment energy consumption, that has the following features:

1. Energy consumption of each home appliance and other equipment such as lighting, heating and cooling systems, and etc. must be recorded in a fraction of an hour at all times of the year.
2. Home/building preferably should have a renewable energy source (such as PV), and its electrical power generation must be recorded for the whole year.
3. Certainly some people should live in this home/building and the equipment is turned on/off by the human (computer simulator should not turn on/off the equipment), because human behavior is important for the research.

Where can I find such a dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I think your query, if you've tried a search engine, is missing "smart home" and/or IoT. Some options:

---

Option one, search on the **[Smart Meter Data Analytics](https://smda.github.io/smart-meter-data-portal/)** platform

> The Smart Meter Data Portal, developed at Georgia Tech ... is part of the National Science Foundation (NSF) Smart Grid Data Analytics Spoke Project. The purpose of this website is to provide a mechanism to researchers to share data and code on Smart Meter Data Analytics.
>
> The website enables researchers to:
>
> - Find public datasets
> - Find applications (code, paper) built on these datasets
> - Share datasets and applications (code and paper links) to increase visibility and citations

---

Option two, to get you started, from this [blog post](https://hub.packtpub.com/25-datasets-deep-learning-iot/) I've pasted several potential data sources and updated any dead links:

1. [CASAS datasets
   for activities of
   daily living](http://casas.wsu.edu/datasets/)

> Several public datasets related to Activities of Daily Living (ADL) performance in a two story home, an apartment, and an office settings.

2. [ARAS Human
   Activity Dataset](http://netlab.boun.edu.tr/WiSe/aras/)

> Human activity recognition
> datasets collected from two
> real houses with multiple
> residents during two months.

3. [Individual
   household
   electric power
   consumption](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Individual+household+electric+power+consumption)

> One-minute sampling rate
> over a period of almost
> 4 years

4. [AMPds dataset](http://ampds.org/)

> AMPds contains electricity,
> water, and natural gas
> measurements at one minute
> intervals for 2 years of
> monitoring

5. UK Domestic
   Appliance-Level (<s>[dead link](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%E2%88%BCdk3810/data/)</s>)

> Power demand from five
> houses. In each house both
> the whole-house mains
> power demand as well as
> power demand from individual
> appliances are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

In a latest *Nature Scientific Data* paper (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-019-0212-5), the author compared his data set *ENERTALK* to others. They are all multi-variate time series describing household electricity consumptions.

[image]

For example, detailed consumptions of house 00 in some day in *ENERTALK* are:

[image]